# NOT NULL constraint failed: snippets_choice.post_id

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

am trying to use the POST method here but it is throwing me an error.

this is Models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    post_text=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    post=models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    likes=models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

this is serializes.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from snippets.models import Post, Choice

class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Post
        fields=['id','post_text']

class ChoiceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Choice
        fields=['id','choice_text','likes']
```

this is views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from .models import Choice, Post
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from snippets.serializers import ChoiceSerializer, PostSerializer

class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset=Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class=PostSerializer
    name='post-list'

class PostDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset=Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class=PostSerializer
    name='post-detail'

class ChoiceList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset=Choice.objects.all()
    serializer_class=ChoiceSerializer
    name='choice-list'

class ChoiceDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset=Choice.objects.all()
    serializer_class=ChoiceSerializer
    name='choice-detail'

class ApiRoot(generics.GenericAPIView):
    name='api-root'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({
        'posts': reverse(PostList.name, request=request),
        'choices': reverse(ChoiceList.name, request=request),
        })
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('post-list/', views.PostList.as_view(), name='post-list'),
    path('post-list/<int:pk>/', views.PostDetail.as_view()),
    path('choice-list/', views.ChoiceList.as_view(), name='choice-list'),
    path('choice-list/<int:pk>/', views.ChoiceDetail.as_view()),
    path('',views.ApiRoot.as_view(),name=views.ApiRoot.name),
]
```

when I try to post:

```
{ 
    "id":3
    "choice_text": "random text",
    "likes": 0
}
```

I got this error:

```
IntegrityError at /choice-list/
NOT NULL constraint failed: snippets_choice.post_id
```

if am providing the id, why it is throwing an error?

even in Postman, it's asking me to put 'choice_text', even when am providing the choice_text.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a choice, and the Choice model relates to the Post model with a not null constrain, so either set the post foreignkey to null

`post=models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

to

`post=models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)`

or you must create a post at first then pass the post id while creating the choice

POST REQUEST TO /post-list/

```
{
   "post_text": "Hello World!"
}
```

it will create a post with a post id lets say post_id = 1

POST REQUEST TO /choice-list/

```
{ 
    "choice_text": "random text",
    "likes": 0,
    "post": 1
}
```